# 3D numpy array dot 2D numpy array to 2D numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy, matrix, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have a numpy array with shape (M,N,N) and a matrix (M,N). I need multiplies both arrays to obtain an array with shape (M,N), ie, for each matrix NxN in 3D-array, multiply with correspond M vector of lenght N of matrix.

I tried the following

```
M, N = 4, 3

A = np.ones((M,N,N))
B = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,0,0],[0,0,0],[1,2,3]])
```

and how, (for example, the first matrix * vector:)

```
np.matmul(np.ones(N, N), np.array([1,1,1]))
>>> [3,3,3]
```

I need to get

```
>>> [[3,3,3],[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[6,6,6]]
```

And also tried np.einsum and np.tensordot but without success.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMViW.jpg)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Matrix multiplication produces a 2D array. If you do multiple matrix multiplications, then you end up with an MxNxN array as the output. But you want a 2D array as output, so those need to be combined somehow. Of the things I tried, the code `[B @ A_elem for A_elem in A]` was closest to what you're asking for.

Comment: I add an image (In a noob way jaja) to try to ilustrate my point

Answer (score 2):

`matmul` works fine, but `B` has to be made (M,N,1), so `M` is the 'batch' dimension.  You squeeze out the 1 after:

```
In [210]: np.squeeze(A@B[:,:,None])
Out[210]: 
array([[3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [6., 6., 6.]])
```

Or with `einsum`:

```
In [212]: np.einsum('ijk,ij->ik',A,B)
Out[212]: 
array([[3., 3., 3.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0.],
       [6., 6., 6.]])
```